# Can't open file using int 21h 3Dh

Tags: file, assembly, emu8086

I am trying to open a .TXT file using emu8086 and `int 21h ah=3Dh`.

I moved the file into "C:\emu8086\MyBuild" folder and when I ran my code I got the following error:

> file does not exist:
>
> C:\emu8086\MyBuild\Í
>
> interrupt error: 21h/3Dh : cannot open file.

After that, I created new folder called "Í" inside MyBuild folder, and when I ran my code I got the following error:

> interrupt error: 21h/3Dh : cannot open file.

This is my code:

```
data segment
filename db "file.txt",0
filehandle dw ?
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:

    xor ax,ax
    mov al, 1h
    mov ah, 3Dh
    lea dx, filename
    int 21h
    mov [filehandle],ax

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h  

ends

end start
```

Comment: You forgot to initialize `DS`.

Comment: If I were working with a 40 year old file system, I would limit myself to plain ASCII file names.